# solana/web3.js StructError: At path: slot -- Expected a number, but received: undefined

Tags: web3.js, transactions

I'm using @solana/web3.js 1.91.0

I'm listening for account changes in a wallet, and then trying to get the transactions, but I very frequently get this error.

```
/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/struct.ts:184
    const error = new StructError(tuple[0], function* () {
                  ^
StructError: At path: slot -- Expected a number, but received: undefined
    at validate (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/struct.ts:184:19)
    at Object.create (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/struct.ts:135:18)
    at coercer (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:418:17)
    at Struct.coercer (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/structs/coercions.ts:25:26)
    at next (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/utils.ts:132:20)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at shiftIterator (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/utils.ts:47:33)
    at validate (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/struct.ts:181:17)
    at Object.create (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/node_modules/superstruct/src/struct.ts:135:18)
    at Connection.getParsedTransaction (/node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:4998:17) {
  value: undefined,
  type: 'number',
  refinement: undefined,
  key: 'slot',
  path: [ 'slot' ],
  branch: [ { meta: [Object], transaction: [Object], version: 0 }, undefined ],
  failures: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

Code:

```
connection.onAccountChange(publicKey, async () => {
    const result = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(publicKey, { until: lastKnownTx }, 'confirmed');
    const signatures = result.filter(r => r.slot).map((r) => r.signature);
    if(signatures.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    
    txs = await connection.getTransactions(signatures), {
            maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
            commitment: 'confirmed',
        });
    lastKnownTx = result[0].signature;
    console.log(txs);
}, 'confirmed');
```

I don't encounter the error when using finalized instead of confirmed, but I would like this to run as fast as possible.I don't understand why the slot is not available. It is the same connection, if the transaction triggered the account change as confirmed, why wouldn't it be available yet when getting the transactions?

Comment: This sounds like a bug, if you can give a transaction signature that reliably produces this error, I encourage you to report it along with steps to reproduce at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js

Comment: After a while I noticed it was a problem with the rcp (quicknode)
My best guess is that the listener was listening to one node, and then the request ended in another node that haven't processed that block yet